# Anchor Error: InstructionDidNotDeserialize

Tags: anchor, rust, react, error, runtime

I was following this tutorial: ["Build a TikTok Web 3.0 Blockchain App with Solana"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIGs3XWybgU) and got around the 2:50:00 timestamp when I tried adding a TikTok, and it gave me this error:

[image: Error Message]

Then I searched and found [this question](https://What%20is%20the%20likely%20cause%20of%20the%20error%20%60The%20program%20could%20not%20deserialize%20the%20given%20instruction%60), but it didn't really help my problem. The answers said this error typically appears because the:

> IDL or client-gen code is out of date and the code is passing incorrectly serialized instruction data to the program.

But it didn't really help my problem as I checked my Rust code, and from what I see there's no problems or errors with it, so I'm not sure what the cause of this error is.

I would really appreciate any help! If you need to see more of my Rust/React JS code, please ask and I will share. Thank you.

### - CODE SNIPPETS -

**create_video (Function in Rust)**: https://ibb.co/rQ2SFh7

**CreateVideo (Struct in Rust)**: https://ibb.co/fQ6s8Lq

**VideoAccount (Struct in Rust)**: https://ibb.co/Y71K0ky

**Video.js (Component)**: https://ibb.co/J52yY9h

**useTikTok.js (Hook)**: https://ibb.co/kh53Zsp

Comment: Kindly include the affected parts of your rust and javascript code

Comment: @Ademola updated post with related files! Thank you.

Comment: Update your question to use code snippets rather than external links. There's no need to worry about length but if you are then the `useTikTok.js` and `create_video` are most relevant to the question.

Also confirm that you're indeed passing strings to your method, and your values are not undefined/null.

Comment: @Ademola thanks, sorry about the external links (I'm new to StackOverflow/Exchange.) I will update that in a second. And when talking about passing strings to my method, are you talking about my JS or Rust?

Comment: It's fine, and I mean js